# Econverter error reading datetime from sqlite database

Tags: sqlite, datetime, delphi, firedac, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have a `SQLite` database with a table where one column is a type of `DATETIME`. Te format of `DATETIME` in `SQLite` table is `yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss`, the format of `DATETIME` in the pc is `mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss ampm`. When i write date to the database, then it is automatially converted to the format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss`. But when i do try to read it from the table, then i get the `econverter` error, which says that `yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss` is not a correct format. My `query` looks like that:

```
sqlQuery.SQL.Text := 'SELECT MAX(Pradzia) FROM Pamainos';
sqlQuery.Open();
ShiftPradzia := sqlQuery.Fields[0].AsDateTime; <-- I do get error here
sqlQuery.Close;
```

If i change `Query` like that, then i do not get any error:

```
sqlQuery.SQL.Text := 'SELECT Pradzia FROM Pamainos WHERE ID = :_ID';
sqlQuery.Params.ParamByName('_ID').Value := fShiftID;
sqlQuery.Open();
ShiftPradzia := sqlQuery.Fields[0].AsDateTime;
sqlQuery.Close;
```

EDIT:
Exact error message:

> Project ProjectName.exe raised exception class EConverterError with
> message "2020-12-19 13:34:24.743" is not a valid date and time.

EDIT2:
Works this way as well:

```
sqlQuery.SQL.Text := 'SELECT Pradzia FROM Pamainos WHERE Pradzia = (SELECT MAX(Pradzia) FROM Pamainos)';
```

Comment: You should give the EXACT error message you get and on which code line. Before accessing a field in the result set, you have to verify that there is actually at lest one: if not sqlQuery.EOF then begin ... end; And as you want to convert to TDateTime, you must be sure the field value has a compatible format.

Comment: @fpiette added excat error message.

Comment: When your default date format is `mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss ampm` then the text `2020-12-19` cannot be converted since `202` is not a valid `mm`. Solution: set the date format that `.AsDateTime()` uses, or use your favorite conversion from text to i.e. `TDateTime`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Using SQLite with FireDAC](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Using_SQLite_with_FireDAC)

> For an expression in a SELECT list, SQLite avoids type name
> information. When the result set is not empty, FireDAC uses the value
> data types from the first record. When empty, FireDAC describes those
> columns as dtWideString. To explicitly specify the column data type,
> append :: to the column alias

Therefore:

```
sqlQuery.SQL.Text := 'SELECT MAX(Pradzia) as "MaxPradzia::datetime" FROM Pamainos';
```

Also you must ensure `FDConnection.Params.Values['DateTimeFormat'] := 'string';` This is the default setting.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite does not have a DATETIME data type ([Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html)).
All datetime values are stored as `TEXT`, or `INTEGER` for Unix timstamps, or `REAL` for Julian days.

I found this: [sqlite .AsDateTime error cannot access field as type DateTime](https://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?t=31931) in another forum with a similar problem and the answer states:

> If you are using concatenation, aggregating functions (MAX, AVG, ...),
> etc., SQLite returns the Unknown type for such fields. For correct
> data display, you should use DataTypeMapping.

Unfortunately the link that the answer provides is broken.

Maybe you can try casting the value returned by your query explicitly to `TEXT`:

```
SELECT CAST(MAX(Pradzia) AS TEXT) FROM Pamainos
```

Comment: "*Unfortunately the link that the answer provides is broken*" - the correct link is: https://www.devart.com/unidac/docs/data_type_mapping.htm